# Showing error on install Firebase/Messaging pod in xcode 11.3?

Tags: objective-c, swift, firebase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MsSg.png)

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

I am trying to install firebase/Messaging, with FirebaseAnalytics but it gives error shown in below. please suggest the solution.

!] Unable to find a specification for `FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (~> 1.5)` depended upon by `FirebaseMessaging`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Comment: There is no image attached.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried updating the pod repo as it suggests?

Comment: You should take a look at the Getting Started Guide [Available Pods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods). Note that your pod is probably out of date so update that, note that *The Firebase iOS library Firebase/Core is no longer needed. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics* and also, we can't see the entire podfile in the question so there may be other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to install the dependencies with below `pod` file without any issues.

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '9.0'

install! 'cocoapods'

target 'PodTest' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```